# I have a questions about the represented values in the chapter “Advanced single bit gates”

Tags: qiskit

I don't understand what are the values of [this table](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/guide/advanced-single-qubit-gates) at the very end is representing.

**My question:**

Does decimal values in the table represent Frequency divided by shots?

Comment: welcome to the site. Unfortunately, as it stands, this question has good chances of being closed for being unclear/too broad. Generally speaking, it is preferred here to (1) ask a single, laser-focused question per post; you can open different posts to ask different questions. (2) Each question should be supplemented with some context, so that people can better understand what you are asking about and what your background is. Feel free to edit the question to this effect

Answer (score 0):

1. The values in the table represent the probability of the object's state before it is measured

As @glS said, please split the questions. I answered the first point. The second point I will answer in a seperated question. This thematic is really complex. It doesn't get easier by having "multi" question. Thank you for understanding (and @glS)